# How to add Designer to the Start up folder of the lotus notes client

Tags: lotus-notes

How can I add the Designer Client to my startup folder in the Lotus Client? I want to put the client in the Windows Startup folder, so it starts first, and then have the that client launch the designer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a empty NSF file in Designer, going to the Database Script and adding LotusScript code that calls the Shell() function in the PostOpen event?

If that doesn't do it for you, I suspect you might just have better luck writing a script (in PowerShell or the scripting language of your choice) that runs the Notes client, waits a minute, then starts Designer, and putting that script in the Windows Startup folder.

Comment: Richard, thanks for your suggestion. I remembered that the Designer is installed by default in bookmarks, and removed it. So I restore the defaults, and Designer reappeared in the Open List. I dragged the icon to the Lotus Startup folder, and that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Richard, thanks for your suggestion. I remembered that the Designer is installed by default in bookmarks, and removed it. So I restore the defaults, and Designer reappeared in the Open List. I dragged the icon to the Lotus Startup folder, and that fixed the problem!